# pigeon hole different solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**Using pigeon hole ,to prove that "whatever" triad of natural numbers, have at least one pair of numbers, those sum must be even.**

What I did, on my way I don't know if it is wrong what I did.Maybe yes, I would like to tell me.

```
I take 3 numbers  example 2 , 4 , 1 . After all those numbers, I add them 2+4+1 =7 .
I take lets say 10 and I did Pigeon hole [10/7]=[1.4]=2 .
```

This is completely wrong right?

Comment: Yes, it's completely wrong.  One example doesn't make a proof, and your example doesn't address the question.  You need to show that the sum of two of the numbers is even.  In this case, $2+4=6$.

Comment: ok thanks ,i just want to know it that i was wrong . Thank you saulspatz

Comment: but if it was 2+4=6 and i take [ 10 / 6]=... will be this right?

Comment: Where does 10 come from? After doing $2+4=6$, you only need to do $6 / 2$ to see if $6$ is indeed an even number.

Comment: really? i didn't know it ,thanks

Comment: First of all one example is not a proof for every number.  Second... I have no idea what you are doing.  Where to the ten come from and why are you dividing by 7 and and what does that have to do with the sum of them being even?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Numbers are either even or odd.  If two numbers are the same they add to an even.  To add to an odd the numbers have to be different.

So  given a choice of even/odd, prove that at least $2$ of the $3$ numbers are the same.  (They can not *all* be different from each other.)

Answer:

> There's only $2$ types of numbers and we have $3$ numbers. So have more numbers than types of numbers so at least two numbers must be the same type.  So those two must add to an even number.

Answer (score 0):

basic idea is this ...

even odd

are containers,

num1,num2,num3

are  objects

assume  1,2,4 then

even has 2,4

odd has 1

we can't change 2, to an odd number $x$ because then

even has 4

odd  1,x

now the sum of two odd numbers is even (2k+1)+(2j+1)=2(k+j+1)

and the sum of two even numbers is even (2k)+(2j)=2(k+j)

so since we no matter what we have a pair in at least one category, we always have a sum that is even.